# CSS dynamic container size with dynamic amount of children

Tags: html, css

How can I create the following behaviour using CSS or Javascript:

- I want to have container (probably flex\grid) that have children
- The container children should be the same size, distributed evenly and cover all the container space (as much as possible)
- The children must keep ratio of 3:4
- The container width, height and the amount of children are dynamic
- The children size should be dynamic based on the height width and the children amount

Partial solution: `https://codepen.io/lerman01/pen/poGNmry`

the problem with my solution is that each time you change the container width, height or amount of children you need to recalculate the value of the container's `grid-template-columns` value

For example

container 550x260 px with 2 children:
[image]

container 550x260 px with 20 children:
[image]

Comment: you can use aspect-ratio css property, plz have a look at MDN docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio

Comment: using aspect-ratio indeed help with keep the children ratio but still their size need to be calculated somehow

Comment: no you don't need to calculate the height or widht of the child, plz refer my code snippet below in solutions (can mark my solution as accepted if it solved your problem) Thanks

Comment: sorry your code not working, try to give specific size to the parent, also all chidlren should be the same size

Comment: Let me clear one thing that if the content in the child element is same then all childs will of same size(height/width), as you said in the problem statement that the children dimensions are dynamic then it does not make any sense to keep all the child of same size (if so then how will be aspect ratio maintained, when content is different but still you want keep then of same size and also maintain the apsect ration, that is not possible), its also mentioned that the container width/height is dynamic too. i guess what you want to achieve is something different (not mentioned in question)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, think that the content of all the children will be images and they will be align to the size of the children, so all children will be the same size, now you have 3 paramters that can be changed: container width, height and amount of children, each time you change one of these parameters the children size need to be calculated in way that they will cover all the container size as much as possible but won't overflow from it, I've added codepen with partial solution on in the original post, please check it out

Comment: You appear to be using grid, have you tried with flex instead? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach is to start by setting the height of child div to its maximum available value (=parent_height - vertical_gap - 2*child_border) and then calculate the child div width by the aspect-ratio condition.

Then we can calculate total-width of divs and check if total-width and total-height are in parent-div bounds. Loop this check by decrementing div height until it fits.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', calc());

var rows, cols, child_width, child_height, child_gap;

function total_width() {
    return cols * (child_width + 2 + child_gap);
}

function total_height() {
    return rows * (child_height + 2 + child_gap);
}

function calc() {
    const container = document.querySelector('.container');
    const container_width = document.getElementById('ct_width').valueAsNumber;
    const container_height = document.getElementById('ct_height').valueAsNumber;
    const number_of_childs = document.getElementById('ch_count').valueAsNumber;
    child_gap = document.getElementById('ch_gap').valueAsNumber;

    container.innerHTML = '';
    container.style.width = container_width + 'px';
    container.style.height = container_height + 'px';
    container.style.gap = child_gap + 'px';

    rows = 1;
    cols = number_of_childs;
    child_height = Math.floor((container_height - rows * (child_gap + 2)) / rows);
    child_width = Math.floor(child_height * 3 / 4);
    while (total_height() > container_height || total_width() > container_width) {
        child_height--;
        child_width = Math.floor(child_height * 3 / 4);
        rows = Math.floor(container_height / (child_height + 2 + child_gap));
        cols = Math.ceil(number_of_childs / rows);
    }

    document.getElementById("ch_width").value = child_width;
    document.getElementById("ch_height").value = child_height;
    document.getElementById("ch_aspect_ratio").value = ((child_width / child_height) * 4).toFixed(2) + ' To 4';
    document.getElementById("coverage").value = Math.round(number_of_childs * (child_width + 2) * (child_height + 2) * 100 / container_width / container_height) + '%';

    for (i = 0; i < number_of_childs; i++) {
        var child = document.createElement('div');
        child.classList.add('child');
        child.style.width = child_width + 'px';
        child.style.height = child_height + 'px';
        child.innerText = i;
        container.appendChild(child);
    }
}
```

```css
#params {
            width: 300px;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: auto 100px;
            grid-gap: 4px;
            margin: 15px;
        }

            #params label {
                grid-column: 1 / 2;
                text-align: right;
            }

            #params input {
                grid-column: 2 / 2;
            }

        .container {
            display: flex;
            align-content: flex-start;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            border: solid 1px red;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        .child {
            border: solid 1px blue;
            background-color: burlywood;
        }
```

```html
<div id="params">
    <label for="ct_width">Container Width =</label>
    <input type="number" id="ct_width" value="550" max="1000" min="200" onchange="calc()" />
    <label for="ct_height">Container Height =</label>
    <input type="number" id="ct_height" value="260" max="700" min="100" onchange="calc()" />
    <label for="ch_count">Count of Childs =</label>
    <input type="number" id="ch_count" value="20" max="100" min="1" onchange="calc()" />
    <label for="ch_gap">Child Gap =</label>
    <input type="number" id="ch_gap" value="3" max="10" min="0" onchange="calc()" />
    <label for="ch_width">Child Width =</label>
    <input type="text" id="ch_width" readonly="readonly" />
    <label for="ch_height">Child Height =</label>
    <input type="text" id="ch_height" readonly="readonly" />
    <label for="ch_aspect_ratio">Aspect Ratio =</label>
    <input type="text" id="ch_aspect_ratio" readonly="readonly" />
    <label for="coverage">Total Childs Coverage =</label>
    <input type="text" id="coverage" readonly="readonly" />
</div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! I thought that my use case able to be solved with only CSS but i guess its not, the small issue with your solution is that you need to do recalculations each change, think of a case that the container width\height is in percentage or it resizable, you need to listen to events in order to recalculate, anyway this is small issue your solution is good enough for me, thanks!

Comment: @Yaniv, you are welcome. I don't think a pure CSS solution is possible because at least JavaScript is needed to add the child divs. The parameters panel is just for convenience to see the effect of changing parameters without changing the code.

Answer (score 0):

To maintain aspect ratio, you can use `aspect-ratio` property in css, we can ignore the height and width, or can use any either `height` or `width` only , incase we have used both `height` and `width` then the `aspect-ratio` will not work properly. Can read more on MDN docs [aspect-ratio](https://aspect-ratio) , also all the major browser supports aspect-ratio property refer [caniuse.com/aspect-ratio](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_aspect-ratio)

```css
.parent-container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.parent-container div {
  border: 1px solid green;
  aspect-ratio: 3 / 4;
  background-color: silver;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
      <div>1 1 1 1 1</div>
      <div>2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2</div>
      <div>3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3</div>
      <div>4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4</div>
      <div>5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's not working, try to add width and height to the parent, the children remain the same size, also all the children should be the same size, see the first example

"The container children should be distributed evenly and cover all the container space (as much as possible)"

Comment: @Yaniv it's working actually, even if there is height/width to the parent element, then only thing you have to take care is to set overflow: scroll , and to make sure that all the child should be equal  just put the content of childs equal. Thanks

Comment: @WasitShafi, you still need to calculate the child divs size based on parent div size and number of children divs. Can not be done without JavaScript.